# How to add several draw interaction to a map

Tags: openlayers

I have an OpenLayer map on which I would like to be able to draw either a Point or a LineString (freeHand) without specifying at first what type of drawing I want. ie : User should be able to click the map and add a point, or mousedown - drag - mouseup to draw a freehand LineString.

I'm able to add two different interactions to the map like this:

```
const freeDrawing = new Draw({
      source: this.drawingLayer.getSource(),
      type: 'LineString',
      freehand: true,
      features: this.drawingFeatures,
      minPoints: 0,
      clickTolerance: 0
});

const pointDrawing = new Draw({
      source: this.drawingLayer.getSource(),
      type: 'Point',
      features: this.drawingFeatures
});

map.addInteraction(pointDrawing);
map.addInteraction(freeDrawing);
```

This works well if I draw several LineString one after another. But whenever I create a Point, and then I want to draw a LineString, LineString begins on mouseup and not on mousedown.

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: cannot reproduce your case but if pointDrawing is added later, it works. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKeXpe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it happens when i try to remove / disable the features on the 'drawend' or 'addfeature' events. In my use case, the user clicks a button to start drawing, and when he's done, the drawing interaction should be disabled until he hits the button again. When reactivating / adding the interactions again, the problem happens. Here's the updated fiddle : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyqMVq

Comment: Ok I actually managed to make this work by removing the interactions on 'addfeature' event, recreating new ones and adding them again.